# What is the correct type for @@ROWCOUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rowcount

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and I need to count the rows affected by a query.

```
DECLARE
    @my_rows                    AS INT
```

and then

```
SELECT *
FROM a table
WHERE some conditions
SET @my_rows=@@ROWCOUNT
```

if I declare my_rows as varchar it works correctly but if I declare as INT I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint.

What is the correct type to declare? I think that the numer of rows could only be integer and betweeb 0 and the total numer of rows.

Comment: I tested your code without any problems. Are you sure you have declared `@my_rows` as `int` and not `tinyint` as the exception states?

Comment: Well, as HarshalY wrote in his answer, the datatype of [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) is in fact `int`. 

When I've tried your code (with an actual select statement) I got no error.  
Your error text suggest that you declared `@my_rows` as `tinyint` instead of as `int`, perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: You will not get that error from the code in the question. Please verify that this actually matches the code you're executing that is producing that error.

Comment: Yes, INT is right. The error came from my mistake as in the original code there were two inverted column so the system tryed to save a varchar value into a tinyint column. Sorry.

Comment: voted to close as typo / can no longer be reproduced based on @Nicolaesse last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per MSDN the correct return type of `@@ROWCOUNT` is int.

SQL code is fine, working properly even `@my_rows` declared as `tinyint`.

Comment: This is a great comment but a poor answer. Please try to thicken it a little bit, perhaps try to explain why the OP is getting an error when attempting to set an int value to an int data type (as he claims).

Comment: It will work properly if @my_rows is declared as tinyint as long as the value returned from the @@ROWCOUNT is not larger then tinyint's max value (255). otherwise there will be an arithmetic overflow error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, i just pointed out between int and tinyint that both are works fine.